# Compare two lists and print out when a change happens

Tags: python, list, for-loop, compare

So me here have been trying to create a script where I compare two lists where I call them old_list and new_list. Old_list is a variable where I use before a While True. And inside the While true is where I use new_list `([line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('newlist.txt')]`. Then my idea was to make a compare old_list with new_list.

I have a Json (newlist) that looks like:

```
{
    "name": "LetsTryThis",
    "grades": [{
            "name": "Stack",
            "pass_grade": 0
        },
        {
            "name": "Over",
            "pass_grade": 0
        },
        {
            "name": "flow",
            "pass_grade": 0
        },
        {
            "name": "com",
            "pass_grade": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

and a code that is:

```
def getGradeChangeNames(old_list,new_list):
    old_grades = {i["name"]: i["pass_grade"] for i in old_list["grades"]}
    new_grades = {i["name"]: i["pass_grade"] for i in new_list["grades"]}
    changed_grades = [old_name for old_name,old_grade in old_grades.items() if old_grade != new_grades[old_name] ]
    return changed_grades


old_list = {'name': 'LetsTryThis',  'grades': [{'name': 'Stack', 'pass_grade': 1}, {'name': 'Over', 'pass_grade': 0},{'name': 'Flow', 'pass_grade': 0},{'name': 'Com', 'pass_grade': 0}]}
new_list = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('newlist.txt')]#For be able to test it you can just copy the same value as old_list and just change the values of pass_grades to 1

    while True:
    test = getGradeChangeNames(old_list, new_list)
    if test != []:
        print("New item found - " + ", ".join(test))
        old_list = new_list
        print(old_list)
    else:
        print("sleep")
        time.sleep(2)
```

The function `getGradeChangeNames()` would return all the names for which grade has changed, either 0->1 or from 1->0.

However what I want my script to do:

I want to create a script where it checks whenever a value changes 0 -> 1 and 1 -> 0. But I want it to only print out when 0 -> 1 happens (print out the 'name') and not when 1 -> 0 happens. However as you can see I have a sleep(2) and what can happen is that I can change the json value `newlist.txt` etc to:

```
{
    "name": "LetsTryThis",
    "grades": [{
            "name": "Stack",
            "pass_grade": 0
        },
        {
            "name": "Over",
            "pass_grade": 0
        },
        {
            "name": "flow",
            "pass_grade": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "com",
            "pass_grade": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

and in that case it should ping 'Over' and 'com' and in the next loop search it shouldn't ping anymore. If the pass_grade goes from 1 to 0 it should update the value without printing out meaning whenever it hits again 0 to 1 it should print out once again.

***My question is:*** How can I be able to print out all values that changes from 0->1 only once and update the value if the value changes from 1 -> 0?

I hope, I really hope I described it correct and if any question, feel free to comment and I will do my best to answer back!

Comment: Can you edit your post to include your actual question in the title and/or body?

Comment: @RandomDavis Will do that right away at the bottom of the post! Thanks for commenting this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I think I have it working. Let me know how the code below works for you. Basically, I noticed that you have a `json` file as you've mentioned but you don't use `json` library to read it in. I am reading the file using json -- so you have an easy dict file to work with from the start. Notice the `import json` at the top. My `test.json` is the `newlist.txt` file that you have therefore just change the name.

```
import json
import time

 def getGradeChangeNames(old_list, new_list):
      old_grades = {i["name"].lower(): i["pass_grade"] for i in old_list["grades"]}
      new_grades = {i["name"].lower(): i["pass_grade"] for i in new_list["grades"]}
      changed_grades = [old_name for old_name, old_grade in old_grades.items() if old_grade == 0 and new_grades[old_name] == 1 ] 
      return changed_grades

 old_list = {'name': 'LetsTryThis',  'grades': [{'name': 'Stack', 'pass_grade': 1}, {'name': 'Over', 'pass_grade': 0},{'name': 'Flow', 'pass_grade': 0},{'name': 'Com', 'pass_grade': 0}]}

 while True:
     with open('test.json') as f:
         new_list = json.load(f)

     test = getGradeChangeNames(old_list, new_list)
     old_list = new_list

     if test != []: 
         print("New item found - " + ", ".join(test))

     else:
         print("sleep")
         time.sleep(2)
```

The conditional statement I mentioned earlier is required I believe. Let me know how this works for you. I was getting the output you wanted: Change from `1 -> 0` is ignored while `0 -> 1` outputs the name.

Also, one major thing I noticed was the disconnect between the `name` field in your `old_list` and the one inside `newlist.txt`; to counter this, I am turning all of the names into lowercase using `.lower()` method for strings. You can see this in `getGradeChangeNames`.

Comment: That could be the issue. I haven't figured out the correct way and I think this is the problem I actually am stuck on :(

Comment: I was wrong. There are a few problems here I think. I'm working on fixing them and will edit my post when I'm done.

Comment: Wow! This is amazing! I think I did find a bug though! So basically if you change etc "Over" to 1. It will notify correct. If you change it back to 0. It doesn't notify which also is good but if you change it back AGAIN to 1 it won't notify for some reason? - A test you can do is that you turn all to 1. When it notify what has changed. Turn back all to 0 and then turn again to 1.

Comment: Whoops, I had missed that test case. Good catch! I have updated my answer. Basically moved the update statement -> `old_list = new_list` outside of the if statement because you want **ALL** changes to be kept track of and not only when we notice a change of `0 -> 1`. Now it works every time you change it for me.

Comment: Correct! I was thinking about it. I added actually `old_list = new_list` in the else statement but your way saves abit more of coding space :) I will try it out more now and see if I can see anything more bug! I will mark this as answer if I haven't seen anything! I really wanna thank you for everything! This meant alot forme

Comment: Nice! Yup, adding it to `else` should work as well. Sounds good. No problem. Glad to help!

Comment: Im marking this as answer since I didnt see any issues when trying all combinations! If anything I will just comment once again :)